# azuread_claims_mapping_policy not working

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-active-directory

I have the following resource in terraform:

```
resource "azuread_claims_mapping_policy" "this" {
  display_name = "Claims Mapping for ${azuread_application.MyApp.display_name}"
  definition = [
    jsonencode(
      {
        ClaimsMappingPolicy = {
          Version              = 1
          IncludeBasicClaimSet = true  
          ClaimsSchema = [
            {
              Source        = "user"
              ID            = "user.onpremisessamaccountname"
              SamlClaimType = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims"
            }  
          ]
          ClaimsTransformation = [{  
            ID                   = "ToUppercase"
            TransformationMethod = "ToUppercase"
            InputParameters = [{  
                ID       = "Attribute"
                DataType = "string"
                Value    = "user.onpremisessamaccountname"  
              }]
            OutputClaims = [{
              ClaimTypeReferenceId    = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims"
              TransformationClaimType = "outputClaim"
            }]
          }]
        }
      }
    ) 
  ]
}
```

[from azure gui]

[image]

I was expecting that the code will do the same thing as in the image attached (add attribute & claims in an enterprise aplication).
Terraform does not give any errors, apply is ok but when checking in gui, I see the default attributes and claims that are made by default when the Enterprise application is made.

Comment: The azuread_claims_mapping_policy module only creates the claims but does not assign them to the application.

Comment: I have a resource azuread_service_principal_claims_mapping_policy_assignment which blocks the attributes an claims (this configuration is managed by a claim mapping policy). It still does not show as I was expecting ToUppercase (user.onpremisessamaccountname)

Comment: I solved this by using MS graph explorer, used query "/v1.0/policies/claimsMappingPolicies" to query the "Attribute and Claims" that I made manually and then modified the terraform code accordingly to apply the new  azuread_claims_mapping_policy.